# Multiuser editing coupled with Google Street view?

Tags: shapefile, editing, arcgis-explorer, google-street-view

I am currently looking for an interface with two essential features:

1. Ability for multiple users to edit data simultaneously
2. Ability for all users to use Google Street View within interface (As an add-in, for example)

My clients have to manually edit data for thousands of buildings based on Google Street View visual information. However they have minimal notions of GIS and I need to provide an editable interface where several users can log in and edit this data simultaneously.

I know [ArcGIS Explorer has a Google Street View Add in](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7508d2ce2fbe4485bebc57f9fe621b71), however does it support the multiuser environment that I am looking for?

Comment: Shapefiles don't support edits by multiple users.  Street View is free as long as someone has an internet connection.  Please tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish and your requirements.

Comment: I have just edited with more details. Please let me know if I can improve it further.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question so that it is focussed on a particular solution and just a single requirement that you have concerns about from your research/testing so far i.e. demonstrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I've re-opened this but I think @Fezter's comment already provides the answer so perhaps that just needs to be converted to one.  I think you need to look beyond shapefiles and even file geodatabases (http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1732&t=303368) to achieve multi-user editing.

Comment: ive re-edited the question to include all sorts of data and not shapefiles necessarily. I am flexible as to data type. Doesnt have to be a shapefile.

Comment: In that case I think your question distils down to whether [ArcGIS Explorer Desktop](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer) can be used for multi-user editing.

Comment: Yes. I think that would be a good start. Thanks for your help. That is basically my question, I will edit it to also address other potential GIS freeware.

Comment: The last edit removed the focus and largely returned this question to "here are my requirements, what are your recommendations" => "too broad"

Comment: One solution would be PostgreSQL/PostGIS for db (supports multiuser editing), QGIS (desktop app.), and QGIS go2streetview plug-in.  All are free to use.

Comment: I just removed the last edit